# Delete text from bars of plotly chart

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

In the plotly bar chart below how can I keep only the `hoverinfo` and skip the text inside the bars?

```
library(plotly)

x <- c('Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C')
y <- c(20, 14, 23)
data <- data.frame(x, y)

fig <- plot_ly(
  data = as.data.frame(data),
  x = ~ x,
  y = ~ y,
  type = "bar",
  marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)',
                            width = 1.5))
  ,
  text = paste(
    "X :",
    data$x,
    "<br> Count of Issue :",
    data$y
  ),
  hoverinfo = "text"
) 

fig
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [very long layout documentation](https://plotly.com/r/reference/#Layout_and_layout_style_objects) about `text`:

> If trace `hoverinfo` contains a "text" flag and "hovertext" is not set, these elements will be seen in the hover labels.

So, we just need to pass in the parameter as `hovertext` instead of `text`.

```r
fig <- plot_ly(
  data = as.data.frame(data),
  x = ~ x,
  y = ~ y,
  type = "bar",
  marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)',
                            width = 1.5))
  ,
  hovertext = paste(
    "X :",
    data$x,
    "<br> Count of Issue :",
    data$y
  ),
  hoverinfo = "text"
) 

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, what is paste() after hovertext? can I just use hovertext=' '?