# Remove text which is displayed on bars in plotly bar chart

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have the `data.frame` below:

```
dp <- structure(list(`Demand Per Section` = c(125, 350, 100, 538, 75, 
25, 138, 138, 75, 150, 37, 225, 35, 40, 125, 25, 25, 125, 50, 
250, 88, 325, 4, 50, 6, 5, 500, 500, 3, 146, 5, 34, 15, 51, 2, 
32, 48, 18, 5, 6, 44, 16, 46, 12, 100, 750, 15, 500, 30, 333), 
    `Element Name` = c("Nitric acid (concentrated)", "Sulphuric acid(concentrated)", 
    "2-hydroxybenzoic acid", "Acetic anhydride", "2-Naphthol", 
    "Sodium Hydroxide", "Phenyl hydrazine hydrochloride", "Glucose", 
    "Sodium acetate", "Aniline", "Zinc poweder", "2-amino-benzoic acid", 
    "1.3-dihydroxybenzene", "Ethyl acetate", "hydroxy benzene", 
    "phenyl methanol", "Sodium carbonate", "Potassium permanganate", 
    "Sodium bisulfite.", "Hydrochloric acid (concentrated)", 
    "Sodium nitrite", "Copper(II) sulfate", "Methyl orange", 
    "EtOH", "Distilled water", "cuper ion", "ammonium hydroxide", 
    "ammonium hydroxide", "Iron( III)", "Potassium Thiocyanate", 
    "ferric ammonium sulfate", "Ammonium Sulfate", "sodium hypochlorite", 
    "Acetic acid", "Phenolphthalein", "Sodium carbonate", "Sodum hydroxide", 
    "Acetic acid", "Phenolphthalein", "Methyl orange", "Phosphoric acid", 
    "Sodium carbonate", "Iron(II) sulfate", "Potassium permanganate", 
    "Sulfuric Acid", "Barium Chloride.monoHydrate", "Distilled water", 
    "nickel Sulphate", "Dimethyl glyoxime (DMG)", "Calsium chloride"
    ), Department = c("Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Physics", "Physics", "Physics", "Physics", 
    "Physics", "Physics", "Physics", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry","Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry"), DemandCourse = c(375, 1050, 300, 
    1614, 225, 75, 414, 414, 225, 450, 111, 675, 105, 120, 375, 
    75, 75, 375, 150, 750, 264, 975, 20, 250, 30, 25, 2500, 2500, 
    15, 730, 25, 170, 75, 255, 10, 160, 144, 54, 15, 18, 132, 
    48, 138, 36, 300, 2250, 45, 1500, 90, 999), `Amount Available` = c(1000, 
    3000, 4000, 1000, 750, 750, 2000, 5000, 150, 24000, 450, 
    3000, 1400, 400, 400, 250, 250, 1000, 1000, 7500, 6400, 900, 
    250, 1500, 20000, 50, 300, 4000, 200, 3000, 500, 1200, 1000, 
    6000, 900, 250, 200, 6000, 900, 250, 200, 250, 150, 1000, 
    15000, 3000, 20000, 1500, 600, 7500)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`1` = 1L, 
`24` = 24L, `32` = 32L, `36` = 36L, `38` = 38L, `42` = 42L, `45` = 45L, 
`49` = 49L, `66` = 66L, `111` = 111L, `140` = 140L, `151` = 151L, 
`154` = 154L, `164` = 164L, `169` = 169L, `171` = 171L, `175` = 175L,`185` = 185L, `193` = 193L, `227` = 227L, `252` = 252L, `253` = 253L, 
`256` = 256L, `257` = 257L, `258` = 258L, `262` = 262L, `263` = 263L, 
`265` = 265L, `275` = 275L, `276` = 276L, `277` = 277L, `279` = 279L, 
`280` = 280L, `281` = 281L, `282` = 282L, `283` = 283L, `284` = 284L, 
`285` = 285L, `286` = 286L, `288` = 288L, `289` = 289L, `290` = 290L, 
`291` = 291L, `292` = 292L, `293` = 293L, `298` = 298L, `299` = 299L, 
`300` = 300L, `302` = 302L, `303` = 303L, `304` = 304L, `308` = 308L, 
`309` = 309L, `310` = 310L, `311` = 311L, `312` = 312L, `314` = 314L, 
`315` = 315L, `316` = 316L, `317` = 317L, `318` = 318L, `319` = 319L, 
`323` = 323L, `325` = 325L), class = "omit"))
```

and I have created the stacked bar chart below.

How to remove the `text` that is displayed on the bars?

```
fig <- plot_ly(x = ~`Element Name`,text=~Department,
               
data = dp) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`DemandCourse`, name = "Demand",
           hovertemplate = "Chemical Name: %{x}<br>Demand: %{y}<br>Department: %{text}") %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`Amount Available`, name = "Amount Available",
           hovertemplate = "Chemical Name: %{x}<br>Available Amount: %{y}<br>Department: %{text}") %>% 
  
  layout(showLegend = T, barmode = "stack",
         xaxis = list(title = "Element Name",tickangle=45),
         yaxis = list(title = "Amount Available"),
         title="Amount and Demand per Element")
fig
```

Comment: Do you mean the legend? If yes, try setting showLegend to FALSE

Comment: I mean the"Chemistry" and "Phsysics" on the bars

Comment: I see, you're probably looking for showticklabels set to FALSE, but i haven't used Plotly with R, so not sure how you would implement it. Usually it's set on the axis of the layout you want to hide it from.

Comment: Or have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70670043/delete-text-from-bars-of-plotly-chart?rq=1 if the showticklabels approach doesn't work out :)

Comment: @firmo23 I'm not sure if SO will notify you - I left an alternative approach below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `textposition = "none"` to each trace so that it is only used in the tooltip.

```
fig <- plot_ly(x = ~`Element Name`,text = ~Department, data = dp) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`DemandCourse`, 
           name = "Demand", 
           textposition = "none",          # <--- added here
           hovertemplate = paste0("Chemical Name: %{x}<br>", 
                                  "Demand: %{y}<br>",
                                  "Department: %{text}<extra></extra>")) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`Amount Available`,
           name = "Amount Available", 
           textposition = "none",          # <--- added here
           hovertemplate = paste0("Chemical Name: %{x}<br>",  
                                  "Available Amount: %{y}<br>",
                                  "Department: %{text}<extra></extra>")) %>% 
  layout(barmode = "stack",                # <--- dropped showLegend (doesn't go here)
         xaxis = list(title = "Element Name", tickangle=45),
         yaxis = list(title = "Amount Available"),
         title = "Amount and Demand per Element")
fig
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `showlegend` goes into the `layout` call just fine - `showLegend` doesn't. The capital "L" is the issue - no need to remove the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion using `hovertext` instead of `text` and `textposition = "none"` is the cleaner approach. `hovertext` is intended to change the hover info.

The `text` parameter on the other hand might be needed later to actually display a text in the plot (unrelated to the hover info).

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(x = ~`Element Name`, hovertext = ~Department, data = dp) %>%
  add_bars(y = ~`DemandCourse`, 
           name = "Demand", 
           hovertemplate = paste0("Chemical Name: %{x}<br>", 
                                  "Demand: %{y}<br>",
                                  "Department: %{hovertext}<extra></extra>")) %>%
  add_bars(y = ~`Amount Available`,
           name = "Amount Available", 
           hovertemplate = paste0("Chemical Name: %{x}<br>",  
                                  "Available Amount: %{y}<br>",
                                  "Department: %{hovertext}<extra></extra>")) %>%
  layout(showlegend = TRUE,
         barmode = "stack",
         xaxis = list(title = "Element Name", tickangle=45),
         yaxis = list(title = "Amount Available"),
         title = "Amount and Demand per Element")
fig
```

Also see this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71478656/9841389).