# Remove name (trace) which is displayed out of the hoverinfo box of plotly bar chart

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have the dataframe below:

```
dp<-structure(list(`Demand Per Section` = c(125, 350, 100, 538, 75, 
25, 138, 138, 75, 150, 37, 225, 35, 40, 125, 25, 25, 125, 50, 
250, 88, 325, 4, 50, 6, 5, 500, 500, 3, 146, 5, 34, 15, 51, 2, 
32, 48, 18, 5, 6, 44, 16, 46, 12, 100, 750, 15, 500, 30, 333), 
    `Element Name` = c("Nitric acid (concentrated)", "Sulphuric acid(concentrated)", 
    "2-hydroxybenzoic acid", "Acetic anhydride", "2-Naphthol", 
    "Sodium Hydroxide", "Phenyl hydrazine hydrochloride", "Glucose", 
    "Sodium acetate", "Aniline", "Zinc poweder", "2-amino-benzoic acid", 
    "1.3-dihydroxybenzene", "Ethyl acetate", "hydroxy benzene", 
    "phenyl methanol", "Sodium carbonate", "Potassium permanganate", 
    "Sodium bisulfite.", "Hydrochloric acid (concentrated)", 
    "Sodium nitrite", "Copper(II) sulfate", "Methyl orange", 
    "EtOH", "Distilled water", "cuper ion", "ammonium hydroxide", 
    "ammonium hydroxide", "Iron( III)", "Potassium Thiocyanate", 
    "ferric ammonium sulfate", "Ammonium Sulfate", "sodium hypochlorite", 
    "Acetic acid", "Phenolphthalein", "Sodium carbonate", "Sodum hydroxide", 
    "Acetic acid", "Phenolphthalein", "Methyl orange", "Phosphoric acid", 
    "Sodium carbonate", "Iron(II) sulfate", "Potassium permanganate", 
    "Sulfuric Acid", "Barium Chloride.monoHydrate", "Distilled water", 
    "nickel Sulphate", "Dimethyl glyoxime (DMG)", "Calsium chloride"
    ), Department = c("Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Physics", "Physics", "Physics", "Physics", 
    "Physics", "Physics", "Physics", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry","Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry"), DemandCourse = c(375, 1050, 300, 
    1614, 225, 75, 414, 414, 225, 450, 111, 675, 105, 120, 375, 
    75, 75, 375, 150, 750, 264, 975, 20, 250, 30, 25, 2500, 2500, 
    15, 730, 25, 170, 75, 255, 10, 160, 144, 54, 15, 18, 132, 
    48, 138, 36, 300, 2250, 45, 1500, 90, 999), `Amount Available` = c(1000, 
    3000, 4000, 1000, 750, 750, 2000, 5000, 150, 24000, 450, 
    3000, 1400, 400, 400, 250, 250, 1000, 1000, 7500, 6400, 900, 
    250, 1500, 20000, 50, 300, 4000, 200, 3000, 500, 1200, 1000, 
    6000, 900, 250, 200, 6000, 900, 250, 200, 250, 150, 1000, 
    15000, 3000, 20000, 1500, 600, 7500)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`1` = 1L, 
`24` = 24L, `32` = 32L, `36` = 36L, `38` = 38L, `42` = 42L, `45` = 45L, 
`49` = 49L, `66` = 66L, `111` = 111L, `140` = 140L, `151` = 151L, 
`154` = 154L, `164` = 164L, `169` = 169L, `171` = 171L, `175` = 175L,`185` = 185L, `193` = 193L, `227` = 227L, `252` = 252L, `253` = 253L, 
`256` = 256L, `257` = 257L, `258` = 258L, `262` = 262L, `263` = 263L, 
`265` = 265L, `275` = 275L, `276` = 276L, `277` = 277L, `279` = 279L, 
`280` = 280L, `281` = 281L, `282` = 282L, `283` = 283L, `284` = 284L, 
`285` = 285L, `286` = 286L, `288` = 288L, `289` = 289L, `290` = 290L, 
`291` = 291L, `292` = 292L, `293` = 293L, `298` = 298L, `299` = 299L, 
`300` = 300L, `302` = 302L, `303` = 303L, `304` = 304L, `308` = 308L, 
`309` = 309L, `310` = 310L, `311` = 311L, `312` = 312L, `314` = 314L, 
`315` = 315L, `316` = 316L, `317` = 317L, `318` = 318L, `319` = 319L, 
`323` = 323L, `325` = 325L), class = "omit"))
```

and I create the stacked bar chart below. The issue with hover text is that the `name` is displayed out of the box and it should be removed from there.

```
fig <- plot_ly(x = ~`Element Name`,text=~Department,
               
data = dp) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`DemandCourse`, name = "Demand",
           hovertemplate = "Chemical Name: %{x}<br>Demand: %{y}<br>Department: %{text}") %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`Amount Available`, name = "Amount Available",
           hovertemplate = "Chemical Name: %{x}<br>Available Amount: %{y}<br>Department: %{text}") %>% 
  
  layout(showLegend = T, barmode = "stack",
         xaxis = list(title = "Element Name",tickangle=45),
         yaxis = list(title = "Amount Available"),
         title="Amount and Demand per Element")
fig
```

Comment: Add `<extra></extra>` to the end of your string in the `hovertemplate` field. For example, `hovertemplate = "Chemical Name: %{x}<br>Available Amount: %{y}<br>Department: %{text}<extra></extra>"`

Comment: thanks you can put is answer.any idea for this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71441124/remove-text-which-is-didplayed-on-bars-in-plotly-bar-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<extra></extra>` to the end of your string in the `hovertemplate` field. For example, `hovertemplate = "Chemical Name: %{x}<br>Available Amount: %{y}<br>Department: %{text}<extra></extra>"`